# Stop replying with "it doesn't work"

Tags: discussion

If I could get just one reputation point for every time I've been replied to or just seen a reply to someone else saying, "it doesn't work", and even seeing it inside a question, I would have been passed the 10K mark long time ago

Nothing drives me up the wall like this. It is the same here at work, if a component fails, they say it is defective or doesn't work.

What does "it doesn't work" means. Go and think about it logically. Take any code in an answer for eaxample. "It doesn't work" is used for the following

- It works, but it is not the desired layout. I want circle, instead I'm getting a square
- It works, but I asked the element to be wrapped in an `a` tag, not a `p` tag
- It works, but there is a bug in the code
- The output is incorrect. Instead of A, B is returned
- If I add the code, I get a white screen of death
- The code has some kind of synatx/parse error
- The code is suppose to return A, but instead it returns A, B and C
- The pagination links does show up, but it does not page to the next page
- The pagination links does not show up as they should. The link is incorrect or the number of pages is incorrect
- The code is totally wrong and is completely not what I was looking for, or according to standards, this code is illegal

And I can go on till by fingers bleed.

My plead is, please stop using those these words. If you really need to be helped, **explain** why something does not work for you, specify the exact problem. You will save everyone a lot of time

Comment: Actually in software the code always work, just not as you expect it to ;)

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: @toscho, no question. Just a general 'guideline' that I use to send someone to who keeps on replying with it doesn't work. It is really annoying when you post code, the OP replies with it doesn't work, you ask him to specify, he replies the same again, and then he asks you to help him. If it is unappropriate, feel free to remove this 'question' :-)

Comment: You could split up this … post into a question and an answer. Right now it reads as if you are not interested in other answers.

Comment: Ever had to deal with (non power-)users bug reports on a project where you're the maintainer / responsible dev? "It does not work" will never die out. Unfortunately. It's like Don Quixote and the windmills...